# How to install Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series in ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Dell inspiron system?

Tags: 14.04

My screen shows

[image: Screenshot]

I don't know how to get the software up in the image

Comment: What *exactly* are you asking? Your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: I have a dedicated graphic card (Radeon HD 7500/7600M) in my laptop, I'm trying to know how to install the relevant drivers to get in recognized by Ubuntu 16.04.