# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

[I found a similar post it wasn't answered so I posted this since I have a similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867052/how-to-install-radeon-hd-7500m-7600m-series-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-on-dell-inspiron)

[Since fglrx is not supported anymore](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04) on 16.04 and the amdgpu doesn't support HD7500M/7600M series we are in a wee bit of a pickle when using some softwares.

This is my card:

```
    otakupup@otakupup-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
otakupup@otakupup-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:63000000-633fffff memory:50000000-5fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

and this what is supported by amdgpu:

```
SUPPORTED HARDWARE
   The radeon driver supports PCI, AGP, and PCIe video cards based on the following ATI/AMD chips
   (note: list is non-exhaustive):

   R100        Radeon 7200
   RV100       Radeon 7000(VE), M6, RN50/ES1000
   RS100       Radeon IGP320(M)
   RV200       Radeon 7500, M7, FireGL 7800
   RS200       Radeon IGP330(M)/IGP340(M)
   RS250       Radeon Mobility 7000 IGP
   R200        Radeon 8500, 9100, FireGL 8800/8700
   RV250       Radeon 9000PRO/9000, M9
   RV280       Radeon 9200PRO/9200/9200SE/9250, M9+
   RS300       Radeon 9100 IGP
   RS350       Radeon 9200 IGP
   RS400/RS480 Radeon XPRESS 200(M)/1100 IGP
   R300        Radeon 9700PRO/9700/9500PRO/9500/9600TX, FireGL X1/Z1
   R350        Radeon 9800PRO/9800SE/9800, FireGL X2
   R360        Radeon 9800XT
   RV350       Radeon 9600PRO/9600SE/9600/9550, M10/M11, FireGL T2
   RV360       Radeon 9600XT
   RV370       Radeon X300, M22
   RV380       Radeon X600, M24
   RV410       Radeon X700, M26 PCIe
   R420        Radeon X800 AGP
   R423/R430   Radeon X800, M28 PCIe
   R480/R481   Radeon X850 PCIe/AGP
   RV505/RV515/RV516/RV550
               Radeon X1300/X1400/X1500/X1550/X2300
   R520        Radeon X1800
   RV530/RV560 Radeon X1600/X1650/X1700
   RV570/R580  Radeon X1900/X1950
   RS600/RS690/RS740
               Radeon X1200/X1250/X2100
   R600        Radeon HD 2900
   RV610/RV630 Radeon HD 2400/2600/2700/4200/4225/4250
   RV620/RV635 Radeon HD 3410/3430/3450/3470/3650/3670
   RV670       Radeon HD 3690/3850/3870
   RS780/RS880 Radeon HD 3100/3200/3300/4100/4200/4250/4290
   RV710/RV730 Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550/4650/4670/5145/5165/530v/545v/560v/565v
   RV740/RV770/RV790
               Radeon HD 4770/4730/4830/4850/4860/4870/4890
   CEDAR       Radeon HD 5430/5450/6330/6350/6370
   REDWOOD     Radeon HD 5550/5570/5650/5670/5730/5750/5770/6530/6550/6570
   JUNIPER     Radeon HD 5750/5770/5830/5850/5870/6750/6770/6830/6850/6870
   CYPRESS     Radeon HD 5830/5850/5870
   HEMLOCK     Radeon HD 5970
   PALM        Radeon HD 6310/6250
   SUMO/SUMO2  Radeon HD 6370/6380/6410/6480/6520/6530/6550/6620
   BARTS       Radeon HD 6790/6850/6870/6950/6970/6990
   TURKS       Radeon HD 6570/6630/6650/6670/6730/6750/6770
   CAICOS      Radeon HD 6430/6450/6470/6490
   CAYMAN      Radeon HD 6950/6970/6990
   ARUBA       Radeon HD 7000 series
   TAHITI      Radeon HD 7900 series
   PITCAIRN    Radeon HD 7800 series
   VERDE       Radeon HD 7700 series
   OLAND       Radeon HD 8000 series
   HAINAN      Radeon HD 8000 series
   BONAIRE     Radeon HD 7790 series
   KAVERI      KAVERI APUs
   KABINI      KABINI APUs
   HAWAII      Radeon R9 series
   MULLINS     MULLINS APUs
```

AMDGPU-PRO supports newer cards only.
[The drivers provided by AMD for Radeon™ HD 6000M and HD 5000M​ Series doesn't have support for 16.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNVtx.png)

So my question/s are:

1. Can I use the AMDGPU driver for my card although it ain't listed
2. Can I use the 15.04 or earlier drivers for my version available for my card
3. Is there anything else I can do other than switching my graphics card?

Comment: `radeon` is used for your card.